# Get the intersection between at least two of three dataframes in R

Tags: r

Here are the three dataframes. Some rows are duplicated in the other one or two dataframes. I want to extract the intersection of rows between at least two of three of them.

```
tmp_df1
   Chr   Start     End Ref Alt Func.refGene Gene.refGene
1 chr1 1647537 1647537   C   T     intronic       CDK11B
2 chr1 1647605 1647605   C   G     intronic       CDK11B
3 chr1 1647699 1647699   C   G     intronic       CDK11B
4 chr1 2030058 2030058   C   T       exonic        GABRD
5 chr1 6199484 6199484   G   A     intronic        RPL22
6 chr1 6602873 6602873   G   A     upstream       KLHL21
    
tmp_df2
   Chr   Start     End Ref Alt Func.refGene Gene.refGene
1 chr1  999258  999258   G   T       exonic         HES4
2 chr1 1637881 1637881   C   T       exonic       CDK11B
3 chr1 1647537 1647537   C   T     intronic       CDK11B
4 chr1 1647605 1647605   C   G     intronic       CDK11B
5 chr1 1647699 1647699   C   G     intronic       CDK11B
6 chr1 2030058 2030058   C   T       exonic        GABRD
    
tmp_df3
   Chr   Start     End Ref Alt Func.refGene Gene.refGene
1 chr1 1041280 1041280   -   C       exonic         AGRN
2 chr1 1647537 1647537   C   T     intronic       CDK11B
3 chr1 1647605 1647605   C   G     intronic       CDK11B
4 chr1 1647699 1647699   C   G     intronic       CDK11B
5 chr1 2030058 2030058   C   T       exonic        GABRD
6 chr1 6199484 6199484   G   A     intronic        RPL22
```

And I want to get the output like this. (The first four rows are intersected among all the three dataframes; and the fifth row is intersected between the first and the third dataframes.)

```
 tmp
       Chr   Start     End Ref Alt Func.refGene Gene.refGene
    1 chr1 1647537 1647537   C   T     intronic       CDK11B
    2 chr1 1647605 1647605   C   G     intronic       CDK11B
    3 chr1 1647699 1647699   C   G     intronic       CDK11B
    4 chr1 2030058 2030058   C   T       exonic        GABRD
    5 chr1 6199484 6199484   G   A     intronic        RPL22
```

Comment: @RonakShah Thank you. I have re-edited my quention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach you can try.

Combine the 3 datasets using `bind_rows`, count the intersection of rows between them and keep the unique rows that occur more than once.

```
library(dplyr)

bind_rows(tmp_df1, tmp_df2, tmp_df3) %>%
  count(across()) %>%
  filter(n > 1) %>%
  select(-n)


#   Chr   Start     End Ref Alt Func.refGene Gene.refGene
#1 chr1 1647537 1647537   C   T     intronic       CDK11B
#2 chr1 1647605 1647605   C   G     intronic       CDK11B
#3 chr1 1647699 1647699   C   G     intronic       CDK11B
#4 chr1 2030058 2030058   C   T       exonic        GABRD
#5 chr1 6199484 6199484   G   A     intronic        RPL22
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use multiple joins:

```
library(dplyr)

Reduce(full_join, list(inner_join(df1, df2), inner_join(df1, df3), inner_join(df2, df3)))
```